# How to make UIDeviceOrientation from automatically becoming portrait when phone is first unlocked?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently making a game that in which if you pick up your phone first, then you lose. Therefore, I have an orientation observer that checks when the phone has been picked up (portrait). However, whenever I lock the phone and then unlock it, the orientation observer automatically thinks the phone is in portrait mode even the phone is face up.

I have tried removing the observer and adding it back after a couple of seconds of unlocking the phone.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { note in

            let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
            if orientation == .faceUp {
                print("yeoo")

            } else if orientation == .portrait {
                print(1)
                if (self.gameMode == "game1") {

                    if (self.host == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) {
                        self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("hostPickUp").setValue("true")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Phone Picked Up", message: "You picked up your phone and must pay the penalty!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I Pay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
                            self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("recent").setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
                            self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("players").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("pickedUpPhone").setValue("true")
                            self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("players").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("time").setValue(self.secs)
                        }))

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call it Even", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
                            self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("callItEven").setValue("true")
                            self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("recent").setValue("calliteven")
                        }))

                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("recent").setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
                        self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("players").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("pickedUpPhone").setValue("true")
                        self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("players").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("time").setValue(self.secs)
                    }

                } else if (self.gameMode == "game2"){

                    self.timer2.invalidate()
                    self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("players").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("pickedUpPhone").setValue("true")
                    self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("players").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("time").setValue(self.secs)
                    self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("finalTime").setValue(self.secs)
                    self.ref.child("games").child(String(self.randNum ?? 0)).child("recent").setValue(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that UIDeviceOrientation doesn't tell you what you need to know. You want to use Core Motion, which uses gravity to tell you the orientation of the device in space.